# Delete an item in a list permanently by accessing JSON file

Tags: json, listview, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am trying to delete an item list when the user taps on a delete button.

i delete the item from the store and the item is successfully deleted from the list , However, when i re-run the application all the items are present .

in order to delete the items permanently i tend to think that i must delete the item in the JSON file , how can i obtain the JSON string of the list and modify it.

i am using the following code for deleting the item :

```
         var store = Ext.getStore('mylist');          
         store.removeAt(index);
         this.getList().refresh();
```

Comment: You must propagate changes to the store to the database before reloading it. Typically this is done via the store's model and its proxy (type REST), and a backend service that supports REST verbs. [See Saki's example here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/restful/restful.html).

Comment: i should note that i am dealing with localstorage .. how exactly will i need to handle RESTful http requests?

Comment: The process is the same regardless of the type of proxy. See [Ed Spencer's post on Ext-JS 4 proxies.](http://edspencer.net/2011/02/proxies-extjs-4.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with localstorage, then you just need to do `store.sync()` to propagate the changes to the store.